# Huawei 3e can't disable apps on Android 8.0

Tags: 8.0-oreo

This is never a problem n7
As of yet the phone isn't rooted yet so any advice be helpful for some apps draining the battery

Comment: Which apps you need to disable? You can disable only system apps. The apps which are installed from play store(user apps) or other sources can't disable. Either you can uninstall or force stop user apps.

Comment: See my solution here: [Enable and disable system apps via ADB](//android.stackexchange.com/a/208271) // You should mention what problem you are having when attempting to disable system apps. Do you not get the option to disable (button greyed out or something)? Also, if your concern is battery drain,  are those apps marked as Optimized for Battery under Battery settings?

Comment: Unfortunately the phone is not rooted and I don't plan on rooting it as it's still under warranty with my previews HTC One M9 I could use an app and it would disable and enable apps on the fly was wondering if anything like that would be possible thanks for your reply so far

Comment: Feel free to post an answer you have found the solution, but please don't post an answer if you want to reply on the comment. On the other hand, you might need to clarify what do you mean by "disable/enable apps on the fly on HTC One M9 using an app", and the name of the app might give you a hint if it's a stock app by HTC (which you can't probably use it on other devices), or 3rd-party app (which you might be possible to download on other devices).

Comment: @Firelord thanks

Comment: @AndrewT. It was rooted and I used app freeze from PS. Okidoki ,,